# Restrict grepping to non-comment lines

Tags: regex, grep, egrep

I need to find in Perl source files lines containing `bin/exim|SendEmail|Unformatted` except of comment lines (lines starting with `#` with possible whitespace before).

I know how to do it with a pipeline of several invocations of FreeBSD `grep` command. Can it be done with only one `grep` (not a pipeline)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
grep -e "^[^#]*bin/exim.*" -e "^[^#]*SendEmail.*" -e "^[^#]*Unformatted.*" test.txt
```

i've try it with this file

```
# test
#test 
 # test
#test
test
toto
#toto
# toto
test
toto
test
#bin/exim 
#SendEmail
#Unformatted
# bin/exim
# SendEmail
# Unformatted
 # bin/exim
 # SendEmail
 # Unformatted
 #bin/exim
 #SendEmail
 #Unformatted
bin/exim
SendEmail
Unformatted
```